# Run-Time Error '9' when removing module Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am sharing a worksheet with a few colleagues. This spreadsheet will eventually be sent to an external party, so we are removing the VBE module programatically as a part of the macro. I used this code which was taken from Microsoft's documentation:

```
 Dim vbCom As Object

    Set vbCom = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents

    vbCom.Remove VBComponent:= vbCom.Item("sample_module")
```

It works for some users, but I get Run-Time Error '9' with others. The rest of the script eventually executes, but the module isn't removed.

Comment: RTE 9 means "this item doesn't exist" - if there's no module named `sample_module` in the `VBComponents` collection, then there's nothing to remove.

Comment: Also, if the rest of the script executes, you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere, and that's probably a bad idea.

Comment: There is a sample_module though. Some users get the error and some do not. For the users who don't get the error, the module is removed. I also don't have any  On Error Resume Next in the script. I feel like I'm not referencing the module correctly, but I'm not sure how to address it.

Comment: Is it possible that the module should be referenced as a part of the worksheet?

Comment: Depends what the heck "referenced as a part of the worksheet" stands for I guess.

Comment: Also what matters isn't that the module exists and is loaded in the VBE, but that it exists **in the ActiveVBProject**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the code with the `For Each vbCom In .VBComponents` loop below, see what you get:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckVBProjComp()

Dim vbCom As Object
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim VbComName As String

VbComName = "sample_module"

With ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    For Each vbCom In .VBComponents
        If vbCom.Name Like VbComName Then
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(vbCom.Name)
            flag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next vbCom
End With

If flag Then
    MsgBox "VB Component " & Chr(34) & VbComName & Chr(34) & " successfully removed", vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to find VB Component " & Chr(34) & VbComName & Chr(34), vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Kudos for removing the `ActiveVBProject` ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. This works quite well. The error isn't showing up anymore.

Comment: @WalterWhalen  you're welcome, you can mark as "Answer" by clicking the gray check mark next to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to the VBA Extensibility library and enable "Trust access to the Visual Basic Project" on each client running those commands. You can see this page from Chip with a great breakdown: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: I thought I was when I was setting vbCom. I also already had the users enable trust access. Should I alter my vbCom reference somehow?

Comment: @WalterWhalen no. Your code is making late-bound calls to the VBIDE API, because you declared `vbCom As Object`.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is simply to remove all modules in a given Excel Workbook, then work off that `Workbook`'s `VBProject`, don't assume the `VBE.ActiveVBProject` is going to be the project behind the workbook you're targeting.

This procedure strips all non-document modules from the specified `target`:

```
Public Sub RemoveAllMacros(ByVal target As Workbook)

    'if the target is ThisWorkbook, we're removing the very macro we're running!
    If target Is ThisWorkbook Then Exit Sub

    Dim components As VBComponents
    Set components = target.VBProject.VBComponents

    Dim component As VBComponent
    For Each component In components
        If component.Type <> vbext_ct_Document Then components.Remove component
    Next

End Sub
```